# What is the best way to remove paint smell from room?

Tags: kitchens, paint, smell

Background.

Ceiling collapsed in small part of kitchen due to water leak, initial damage was limited to small part of room, but somehow the people who landlord sent round (not professionals), they have made a mountain out of a mole hill, but straight to the point of the paint issue.

My landlord insisted on the room been painted, although my priority was just to get it usable again, I backed down, painter arrived and I said just paint over the new plaster, dont care about the rest (previous people who came were already making a mess of things).

He seemed to be taking an age to do this small job, an hour or two later he tells me he is done and of course he had painted the entire kitchen, the initial damage I noticed was paint over cupboards, in the sink on some switches, tiles etc.  But smell wasnt too bad.

Window was left open until night time and I shut it, by this time smell had increased a little.

Next day smell was so bad, I had to run to window covering my nose to open it, then get out the room shutting the door behind me.  By end of day no improvement.

Third day today, its no improvement, is enough wind to keep moving the door back and forwards (it doesnt stay shut well), yet no improvement to the stench.  The whole thing has become a complete nightmare.  (other issues which I omitted form this question).

Answer (score 1):

If there's a window in the kitchen, open it and leave it open. Put a fan, a big box fan would be best, but any fan will do, in the window pointing out, to help pull air out of the room. Open other windows in the house to allow fresh air in. Put another fan, again bigger is better, but anything will do, in the doorway to the kitchen blowing fresh air into the kitchen.

Between the two fans, you'll be pushing fresher air into the kitchen and pulling the smelly air out the window. This will speed airing out the kitchen as much as possible.

If it's been more than 24 hours, most folks won't notice the smell much any more. Unless you're extremely sensitive to the smell of paint (and some people are), it seems that something odd is going on. Most paint sold today is low VOC and low smell. If it's still really that bad, I'd suggest you see if you can get the landlord to stop by and take a whiff. At least that way, he'll see first hand the mess the painter left behind and what it still smells like. He may even have a couple of fans you can borrow to make it better.

Unfortunately, as the tenant, you have to live with it, but it's his property, one would think he'd be vested in making sure it's well taken care of, not only by you, but by anyone he hires to do work on it.

Comment: The smell vanished over night when the old carpet was removed, so I think somehow the carpet was generating the smell.